# Android Chromium WebView App is closing after sometime

Tags: javascript, android, memory-management, webview, chromium

I have an android app which has webview working with local html files and cross origin webservices. From my native part, within an interval I run a javascript function. After some time my app close itself by animating some black blocks on webview.

What can be the problem?

Comment: The amount of information you have provided is not enough to understand what could cause the problem

Comment: I'm doing ble scan. And in every 350ms result of scan is sending to the webview via js function. Almost after six minutes app shuts down some how

Comment: please add this to the qestion body. Also do you have any crashlog? Because first impression is that it could be memory leak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the write here.. I solve the problem by using crosswalk instead of android stock webview component.